# mastercard Fraud Scoring for Merchants not add sdk

Tags: c#, mastercard

I want to call Fraud Scoring for Merchants api.So i use nuget intall MasterCard-FraudScoring. My project's framework 4.5. vs2013 .When i using MasterCard,it's error is Failed to find the type or namespace name "MasterCard" (does it lack the using directive or assembly reference?)
 I change framework from 2.0 to 4.5. and change the reference of file directory.It still not work. You can see the Object Browser exists the method. Plz,help me ,thanks.

Comment: what coding language you are using in your project ?

Comment: c# language i use.

Answer (score 0):

No one answer me.So I find other way to do.I found https://github.com/Mastercard/mastercard-api-csharp,and if you can't compile, you can see issue,to resolve this problem.If you use this compile sdk,it works.I hope it can help you if the one meet this problem.